# Colab 'ascii' codec can't decode byte: ordinal not in range(128) with encoding="utf-8"

Tags: python, character-encoding, google-colaboratory

I am struggling with an issue that I have only on Colab and not on my machine.
I am reading some JSON files and it throws a `UnicodeDecodeError`:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 418: ordinal not in range(128)`

which is not totally surprising since these files actually contain non-ASCII characters, and in effect, in that position on that file there is that non-ASCII character.
But I typically solve the issue by adding `encoding="utf-8"` parameter to the `json.load` function, while here it does not have any effect. Do you have any idea on how I could solve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
```